# How to remove "Paypal payments" tab from My Account in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, hook-woocommerce

The [Woocommerce Paypal Payments](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-paypal-payments/) plugin adds a "Paypal payments" tab on the Woocommerce My Account page. How do I remove this tab entirely?

I have tried this snippet modified from one found [here](https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/my-account-menu.html) but was unsuccessful in removing the tab.

```php
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'misha_remove_my_account_links' );
function misha_remove_my_account_links( $menu_links ){
        
  unset( $menu_links['ppcp-paypal-payment-tokens'] );
        
  return $menu_links;
        
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track! That plugin adds that tab on priority of `40`. So, you could add a filter on a higher priority, let's say `50`, like this:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'misha_remove_my_account_links', 50);

function misha_remove_my_account_links($menu_links)
{

    unset($menu_links['ppcp-paypal-payment-tokens']);

    return $menu_links;
}
```

And poof! That extra tab is gone!

[image]